# What is the difference between request, response and server?

Tags: client-server, request, response

What is the difference between request, response and server?

Comment: who subtract my score just now? why?
can you give me a reason?
i'am just a freshman in stackoverflow.com!

Comment: I suppose people are downvoting you because this is a very general question without much context about what you really want/need to know. It is the kind of thing someone without any knowledge of computers would ask.

Comment: haha ,maybe you are right,i just want to test this website's function.
i think this is a special website.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Request :** From Client to Server
**Response:** From Server to Client
**Server:** Receive Request and Send Response
**Client:** Send Request and Receive Response

Comment: simple answer and simply understand it

Answer (score 6):

A client (web user) makes a **Request** to a **Server** which processes the **Request** and determines the appropriate **Response**

Answer (score 1):

Server: Machine that provide something for client.

Focus at Server, 
Request is message that arrive to server for request something.
Response is message that send from server to client for give thing that client what.

anyway REQUEST/RESPONSE means you can know it with common sense.

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response

Answer (score 0):

The 1st answer (Ramesh Soni's answer) is simple and concise. I also wanna share a useful terms distinction that's relevance to this.

## What's the difference between request and query???

- First of all, **query and request can both be nouns and verbs**. E.g:

  - I requested a refund.
  - We received a request for a refund.
  - I queried the price.
  - We received a query about the price.
- To request something is to ask for something, an object or a favour etc. A request is a *polite demand*. To query is to ask about something i.e. you are ***wanting information***. *A query is a question*.
- Also, QUERY is an inquiry(*Query and inquiry are synonyms*)
  They are both requests but the difference is that the **QUERY is a precise request**. In informatics, if you need information about something you need to send a *specific* request with precise information.

"I queried information about user account Maxim Pavlov" = "I need to know about this website users. In particular, I need to know if there is any Maxim Pavlov registered on this site".

- If you are Arabic, best translations in Arabic would be, *request = طلب and query = إستعلام*)

Comment: Please refrain from copy paste from google. https://www.italki.com/question/311940?hl=en 
Also please avoid adding redundant information or add answers to questions that have not been asked.

Comment: For the sake of your reputation, I would friendly recommend you to modify your answer to something that is useful and original, before it gets downvoted.